# Active Admin and STI model error: Could not find table 'categories'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, single-table-inheritance, sti, activeadmin

**Update #1: Solved!** Somehow Pow did not restart it's processes, so after updates it was loading the old config files. And it was loading the wrong locale file.

I deleted gems I installed recently (only from Gemfile) and restarted Pow. Then one by one I added gems back to the Gemfile. As well ActiveAdmin as Rails localization started working normally.

**Original question:**

I am trying to setup ActiveAdmin to support my taxonomies. My setup is as following:

```rb
class Taxonomy < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Category < Taxonomy
  has_ancestry # implements a tree of categories
end

class Tag < Taxonomy
end
```

So now I added the following to ActiveAdmin:

```rb
ActiveAdmin.register Category do
end
```

And it returns the folioing error:

```
Could not find table 'categories'
```

My migrations were definitely ran. And I have some valid STI records in the `taxonomies` table. So what can be wrong?

Comment: Can you confirm whether the `categories` table does indeed exist?

Comment: No it doesn't. STI (Single Table Inheritance) pattern implies that you can have one table for multiple models that have (almost) same attributes. In my case attributes are `title` and `description`. However to differ between the models there **MUST** be `type` attribute. Rails will then automatically match this attribute with model name. So when I call `Category.all` I'll get the same as `Taxonomy.where(type: 'Category')`.

It does work on the frontend, but it doesn't in ActiveAdmin. So maybe I forgot something.

Comment: where you able to solve this?